# is the graph $G$ determine unique by the eigenvalue?

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

the graph $G$  have eigenvalue 2, 1, 0, -1 and  -2 and frequent of the eigenvalue Respectively 1, 2, 1, 2 and 1. 
is the graph $G$ determine unique by the eigenvalue?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not determined by its spectrum. It’s cospectral with the union of $C_6$ and an isolated vertex.